# Set a column limit on R's str() function

Tags: r

The R `str` function reaches column 182 if you give it a data frame containing (for example) a vector of UUIDs, which is pretty ridiculous-looking and makes stuff hard to find. What are the alternatives, or can I make `str` obey hard column limits?

Comment: Just subset the data.frame?

Comment: Takes too long. I deal with large data frames with lots of predictors or attributional data every day, I'd have to find column names, do it multiple times per week, and it's not a process thing. If it's awkward but necessary for a process, fine. I just want to view the structure of the data frame in a graceful way; basically I need the `tbl_df` equivalent for `str`.

Comment: "Ridiculous-looking" sort of tells us what you don't like about what you see, but doesn't do much to narrow down what you do want to see. If you have details to add, please edit them into the question. If it's just "what are the alternative tools?", that's usually seen as an unsuitable question for this site (#4 here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of searching through the help file, I found a couple of arguments that may be of interest.

```
 str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ b: num  -1.207 0.277 1.084 -2.346 0.429 ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 10 levels "Alabama","Alaska",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Then, you can use the list.len argument to reduce the number of columns shown to the first n of them.

```
# show the first two columns
str(df, list.len=2)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ b: num  -1.207 0.277 1.084 -2.346 0.429 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

A drawback here is that it will not allow you to skip columns or select them individually. You can also limit the number of example elements shown for each vector with vec.len, though this apparently does not affect factor variables.

```
str(df, vec.len=1)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 ...
 $ b: num  -1.21 ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 10 levels "Alabama","Alaska",..: 1 2 ...
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=rnorm(10), c=state.name[1:10])
```

Comment: Nice, didn't see about the argument `vec.len`, that's much nicer to look at when the elements of several vectors all contain long strings.